# react js bootstrap treeview href

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-router

Is use the adminlte template for react. (not the react version) I am struggle to get the sidebar right. The problem is I cannot get the a href right. See example

```
  <li className="treeview">
        <a href="#!">
          <i className="fa fa-user" />
          <span>Hoofdtrainer</span>
          <span className="pull-right-container">
            <i className="fa fa-angle-left pull-right" />
          </span>
        </a>
        <ul className="treeview-menu">
          <li>
            <Link to="/admin/trainingen">
              <i className="fa fa-book" />
              <span>Trainersgroepen</span>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/admin/trainingen/cursisten">
              <i className="fa fa-book" />
              <span>Cursisten</span>
            </Link>
          </li>
```

Is there a way to active the treeview by the react-router? Or is er a way to change the href value